# Multiplying two columns from two different tables

Tags: sql

I'm trying to sum multiply two columns from two different tables but I keep getting different results. What I really want is to have the shares from the HoldingReport table to be only from a distinct CustomerServiceId. For example If CustomerServiceId = 2 then the shares should be multiplied with the current value of whatever stock they have and summed for only those columns with CustomerServiceId = 2.

These are the two tables:

[image]

[image]

And the query I have is:

```
SELECT SUM(CurrentValue*Shares) AS TotalAUM
FROM Stocks,HoldingReport
WHERE CustomerServiceId = '2'
```

Comment: Why are you choosing not to use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax?

Comment: Could you explain how I would use the JOIN syntax in this situation?

Comment: FROM stocks s INNER JOIN HoldingReport h on s.CustomerServiceId = h.?? <- I guess there is also a customerServiceId ?

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, the query you want is:

```
SELECT SUM(s.CurrentValue * hr.Shares) AS TotalAUM
FROM Stocks s JOIN
     HoldingReport hr
     ON s.stocksid = hr.stocksid
WHERE hr.CustomerServiceId = 2;
```

Note that `CustomerServiceId` looks like a number, so I removed the single quotes.  One use single quotes for string and date constants.  (Of course, if it is really a string, then keep the single quotes!)